# Discord Slash Command Bot - Python Structure

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

As Discord has brought a new feature, which after reading [the docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/slash-commands#what-is-a-slash-command) for hours, I have basic understanding about that this feature is completely new and actually a bit more complex that supposed to be. The basics are that you might have never done before is that through OAuth2 page of your bot, you have to check "applications.commands" option alongside "bot" box, in order to give your bot a slash command ability throughout the servers it is in.

Unfortunately, Discord really supports the JavaScript made bots much more than the Python ones, and the documentation, whole process of making the bots, even the structure is supposed to almost always have a JS type of something, here for example, for the [configurations](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/slash-commands#what-is-a-slash-command) the json is being used.

I have found a lot of samples regarding to the JS written slash command bots both recorded and blog written, however, not any related to the Python made. Is there any sample where to just to run the bot and use a simple slash command integrated within our bot in our server to get to know the general structure of how slash bots are made in Python?

p.s: I am still in search for the resources, and if found anything, this message will be updated, and the links to the resources will be provided down below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/6149

> TL;DR - Unfortunately, it appears discord.py proper is unlikely to support slash commands due to some drawbacks in comparison to ext.commands. There is a non-supported fork which one may use.

Sadly, it seems this fork is your only option, and that it's unlikely you'll get a better solution in the near future.

Comment: thanks for taking your time and putting on research to find an understandable template. I will check it now. Thanks once again.

Comment: @woosal You're welcome! When you have issues regarding a library, I recommend going to their GitHub and simply entering keywords to look through their open issues (here, I just looked up "slash", I believe)